# Show Bottom Navigation outside Bottom Navigation Pages

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have in design a Bottom Tab Navigation in a page that isn't in the Bottom Tab group of pages... Is it possible to do?

My Bottom Tab Pages are "Station", "Home" and "Menu". I have a "Form" screen, and in the UI this Form has the Bottom Tab... Is it possible in React Native?

It seems like impossible and I didn't find nothing in docs (React Navigation / React Native)

Edit: Putting a design example.

[image: Design Image]

Pay attention, in the image above, the "**Workers Form**" isn't in the bottom menu group of pages, but I need to show the bottom menu in this page too (Workers Form)...

I didn't find any information about it in React Navigation docs, so I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I've just added an image. Thanks!

Comment: you can embed a stack navigator inside the Bottom tab navigation. Please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65754247/7704650)

Comment: @emkarachchi It will solve my problem... Thx! If you want to publish the answer, I'll point it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to embed a `Stack.Navigator` inside your `Tab.Navigator`.Please refer to my answer [here for a code example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65754247/7704650)